# change style of material-ui checkbox

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, material-ui, styled-components

I am using React for my project and `styled-component` package for styling, but I have problem with styling the Material-ui checkbox with styled-component. I need to narrow the border of checkbox, but I can't find any interface of the Material-ui for styling the border width.

This is my current code:

```
const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  svg{
    color: #CDCDCD;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
`
```

for styling the `svg` of checkbox component. I don't know which `props` of `svg` deal with the border width of the `svg`. I have tried some `props` like `font-weight`, `border-width`, but they both doesn't work.

Codesandbox button: [image: Edit vv50o01x2l]

expected result:

[image]

current result:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `border-radius`?

Comment: I did also try this, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the good way is to pass a new icon in prop `icon` of Checkbox.

```
 <StyledCheckbox
    checked={checked}
    onChange={onChange}
    color="primary"
    icon={<CustomIcon />}
    {...others}
 />
```

`<CustomIcon />` could be:

- custom svg with exact style you need.
- React/Styled component with css ( that could be a div with border, borderRadius, width, height properties).

Doc: https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#props